# How to change Java AES ‐ CBC with PKCS5 Padding to PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes, php-openssl

I am trying to change JAVA Encryption to PHP and produce exactly the same result. 
I have the following guidelines. 
AES ‐ CBC with PKCS5 Padding Symmetric Encryption Scheme:

Encryption key size would be of 128 bit size.

Initialization Vector (IV) :

-​New Random IV would be used in each request.
-​In a single web‐service request, same IV would be used while encrypting all the encrypted fields.
-​This IV would be passed in SOAP Header with name as “IV”. IV value would be Base64 encoded.

I have tried this https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/fae409eaae2abcf83bd6633b961e7f00

```
public class AESEncryptionUtil {
public static final String CLASS_NAME = AESEncryptionUtil.class.getName(); private static final int KEY_SIZE = 16;
private static final String ALGORITHM_AES = "AES";
public final static String ALGORITHM_AES_CBC = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

private static Key generateKey(String keyValue) throws Exception { Key key = null ;
if (keyValue!=null && keyValue.length()==KEY_SIZE){
byte[] byteKey = keyValue.substring(0, KEY_SIZE).getBytes("UTF-8");  
key = new SecretKeySpec(byteKey, ALGORITHM_AES);
}else{
System.out.println("Not generating the Key!! "+keyValue); }
return key; 
}
/**
* Return Base64 Encoded value of IV *
* @param keyValue * @return
* @throws Exception */
public static String generateIV(String keyValue) throws Exception { String iv = null ;
Key key = generateKey(keyValue); if (key!=null){
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_AES_CBC); cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); AlgorithmParameters params =     cipher.getParameters();
iv = new BASE64Encoder().encode(params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV()); 
 }else{
System.out.println("No IV generated ...");
}
return iv; }

/**
* Method to perform encryption of given data with AES Algorithm / Key and IV. * @param encKey -
*​Encryption Key value * @param plainVal -
*​Value to be encrypted * @return - encrypted String Value * @throws   Exception
*/
public static String encrypt(String encKey, String plainVal, String currentIV) throws Exception {

String encryptedText = null ; Key key = generateKey(encKey);
if (key!=null && currentIV!=null && plainVal!=null){
 Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_AES_CBC);
 c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(currentIV)));
byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(plainVal.getBytes()); encryptedText= new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
}else{
System.out.println("Invalid input passed to encrypt !! keyValue="+encKey+", IV="+currentIV+", valueToEnc="+plainVal);
}
return encryptedText; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get something to work

```
<?php
$string = "online1234";
$key = "haskingvista127$";

$iv  = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc')));

$encodedEncryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv)));

$decryptedData = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encodedEncryptedData), "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv));

?>
```

Hope this might help someone else